# Is it possible to use Keras's .fit_generator() to train and predict Bounding Boxes for object detection?

Tags: python, keras, object-detection, prediction, bounding-box

I'm working on a project that needs me to use keras to predict bounding box coordinates (object detection). I was brainstorming and want to try if it is possible to modify/use keras's `ImageDataGenerator` and `.fit_generator()` to predict bounding box?

I am seeking online documentation to help me figure out. So far I have not found any links that takes in an input of bounding boxes in `.fit_generator()`.

Comment: you can just consider a regression problem.

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi Would you mind explaining a bit further on how to use fit_generator for that?